# Need help in mysql RIGHT join

Tags: php, mysql

here is mytable structure?

```
table:category
id name
1  x
2  y

table:subproduct
id cat_id name myval
1  1      xyz  test
2  1      abc  test2
```

So basically i want to select all values from subproduct for each id of category table and show it in array in php?

here is my PHP code

```
$sqlnew = "SELECT c.cat_id,c.cat_title,s.sub_id,s.sub_title,s.store_cashback FROM category c JOIN subproduct s ON c.cat_id = s.pid";
$pdo = getDB();
$stmtnew = $pdo->query($sqlnew);
$resultnew = $stmtnew->fetchAll();
var_dump($resultnew);
```

I am using PHP PDO.

Comment: You have not given any PHP code or even mentioned what method you are using (mysql, mysqli, pdo). Are you just looking for the MYSQL part of the answer?

Comment: Could you state more specifically what you want the end result to look like? Do you want to iterate through each category ID and see all the products? Or have a multidimensional array where the category IDs are keys for arrays of products?

Comment: yea @bytesized i want category IDs are keys for arrays in Multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all items with a particular category ID, you should do something like this:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subproduct INNER JOIN category " .
     "ON category.id = subproduct.cat_id WHERE category.id = :id");
$statement->bindValue(":id", $category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$data = $statement->fetchAll();
```

You could use this to individually fetch each category ID and build an array like this:

```
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM category;");
$ids = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$data = array();
foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subproduct INNER JOIN category " .
         "ON category.id = subproduct.cat_id WHERE category.id = :id");
    $statement->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
    $data[$id] = $statement->fetchAll();
}
print_r($data);
```

I am not crazy about this because it looks inefficient and I don't like looping through queries. You could also request all the data at once and then rearrange it:

```
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM subproduct");
$data = array();
while($subproduct = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id = $subproduct['cat_id'];
    if (!isset($data[$id])
        $data[$id] = array();
    array_push($data[$id], $subproduct);
}
print_r($data);
```

I don't really like this either because using PHP to sort MYSQL data feels wrong since that is MYSQL's job. I could have requested MYSQL sort the data, but then the data would still need to be broken up into a multi-dimensional array, so I am not sure that helps.

Comment: actually i want all data from subproduct for each category id?